# how to get session variable value in php?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, echo

Inside my code i can see one session and once i printed that session i got following things in view source

```
Array
(
    [Config] => Array
        (
            [time] => 1406983421
            [timeout] => 10
        )

    [loggedIn] => 1
    [user] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 424

                    [correspondence_email] => 
                    [terms] => Y
                    [old_facebook] => 
                    [[old_twitter] => 
                    [gmail_email] => 
                     [login_count] => 9
                    [last_secdeg_updated] => 2014-08-01 08:47:35
                )

        )
)
```

then i tried this line to get the value of "login_count"

```
echo "value".$this->Session->read("login_count");
```

but am not able to see this the "login_count" in echo.
am getting only this result  in viewsource

```
value
```

How do i get "login_count" vale to a variable.?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using CakePHP? Can you post the code you're using to write to the session? Thanks.

Comment: `$array['user']['User']['login_count'];` ?

Comment: Hi ,yeah am using cake php, but i couldnt find the code for adding session (its written by some other guy)

Comment: according to the docs http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#interacting-with-session-data and http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-dot-notation you could try -> `$this->Session->read("user.User.login_count");`

Comment: ok i will try your cods now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code that writes the session, I am suspecting that this is what you're looking for:

```
echo $this->Session->read('user.User.login_count');
```

Comment: @user3755198 How'd you make out?

Comment: echo $this->Session->read('user.User.login_count'); was working, thnks

Comment: @user3755198 Glad to hear you got it working, thanks for the update!

Comment: can u check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101584/not-able-to-restart-apache2-in-local-azure-instance

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo $this->Session->read('user.User.login_count');
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to create any codes to perfom session operations.They are already built in the cake php api.You just need to read and write the sessions from the link i given below.

```
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html Used in Controllers

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html Used in Views
```